# Схема комбинированных сложных предложений

Tags: синтаксис

> В саду было просторно и росли одни только дубы; они стали распускаться только недавно, так что теперь сквозь молодую листву виден был весь сад с его эстрадой, столиками и качелями.

[На этом сайте](http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=814.tEwzB_lGWno-L_L-l2Fu-lT00CTbL8xEBdn1KI_V1d3V4HiK_AYNlR5VYIfifaRY-gpHTccqHS_-BNi7CeFemcl218wOsFSpmgTdNPWAAkk.caccc08769c4ed7a7647dc12f92684dfaa0886c0&url=http%3A%2F%2Fvideotutor-rusyaz.ru%2Fuchenikam%2Fteoriya%2F307-slogn&uuid=&state=PEtFfuTeVD5kpHnK9lio9XPOnieP7YQBovzVqj9ang0YEepmskggOQ%3D%3D&data=&b64e=3&sign=f723ad7b62b8150aa0df4762c4c503f7&keyno=0&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ5Hyx_fyvalFFO69YeYKfJ67Gvax84D5dKtZ9EIUQdN6ianTiC-L_0UYoEHQ9KLxzpZizoQrEiQoifooFWiA--3u1NQTovvJudQP74nv48HhpU8xjs3Cl98ezbEHkrLfW7tfAYlbw2hIIIVYI3_vmppIEwqpZ-v3R6Ne5L4irlpBgnl3ANTw5WySOoDBQQ0ZAI&ref=cM777e4sMOAycdZhdUbYHpMQ80108_UCNQCW31z695H0nKLPu3GKO2z1WrMNadc8BZcFDHUQPxd6s6my_1EJPHEUSoWMwoa3dq32FRYoi6gAX8uj6Q-mFkrOvIn18XFW8-V0HTv2Z5rMwCtB2FV8dDFyqdxoi0_addAOJD_LPF5Xu4hPA54EAcUywaLKvui3teUGxBMl7SQHyUT_WSK2JnSQWIGSaUJgM5yJj2snBqHMS4UGocOiKpctxM8h5I2zM4OFKBRbyp2Xfx91T_ZwGxty1g4vFQQq-ZQfBJR9LsOs0nkHxWycd2QRdbXai0zW0_F1mlneReFEsu6WrZkDHGGNVVZWToXoFYPCEzGr1RRcXOQaY8Rx8Iibor0CYmZa2JEMX_-_tCwUoJ0JQhXOYbjK_9zFxerb6AfOW3H8F_X5YUNrW5p0zGSZziKBr4ipnHgP5zU-2j6AChND4sqMRLZHRkkGhoNUXgNbVZMxxGJ-KjchB_hzhdQbJjYWCayE_26IpKbWQDao7esFZVnz73iVeYGIbLpaCUEBvzWHPZlx6eJSlXL2F9Z6o3E6wdAdetnkWlREnhqJNkZHoympfJseMPVwMUvxN7BRPBCodhwYqwwWuBLiGQLuhJEbg-mhTBQMbGwH5hs&l10n=ru&cts=1442525216613&mc=4.31535184797577) дается такой разбор вышеприведенного предложения:

`[ ] и [ ] ;[ ] ,[ ] ( так что...)`.

В первых трех частях представлена самостоятельная предикативная основа, в четвертом - подчинительная связь. А где тогда четвёртая самостоятельная связь, которая обозначена на схеме?

Может, на сайте ошибка?

Comment: Ваш линк даёт "Ошибку 404".  Поправьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: Странно, у меня открывается.

Comment: Возможно, на Вашем компьютере какая-то специальная идентификация имеется, вроде cookie от Яндекса.

Comment: Заново скопировал ссылку. Посмотрите, пожалуйста, открывается?

Comment: Да, открывается. Спасибо.

Comment: "И" - сочинение, "так что" - подчинение, точка с запятой - бессоюзная связь.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ошибка, конечно. Объяснить могу только тем, что в некоторых изданиях "Учителя словесности" можно встретить такое предложение:

> В саду было просторно и росли одни только дубы; деревья были невысокие,они стали распускаться только недавно, так что теперь сквозь молодую листву виден был весь сад с его эстрадой, столиками и качелями.

Вот к нему схема подходит. Но как они ухитрились их соединить, объяснить не могу. Так наши тьюторы деньги зарабатывают: одно с одного сайта стащат, другое с другого.

Comment: Сайт не плохой, вроде.

Comment: Да, неплохой, но бывает и на старуху проруха. Если и дальше будете так же внимательны, всё будет нормально